# Disable interaction in Spannable

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

How can I disable interaction in a `Spannable`, without affecting the interaction of the `TextView` that displays it?

In other words, I would like to disable all links in a given `Spannable`. I can't assume anything about the spans (in particular, they can be `ClickableSpan` subclasses that override `updateDrawState`).

**What I tried**

`textView.setEnabled(false)` is not good enough, as it also disables any click/touch listeners added to the view.

`textView.setClickable(false)` doest not disable `Spannable` links.

Comment: you could remove the span?

Comment: @blackbelt But I would loose other properties (e.g., bolding), wouldn't I?

Comment: then replace the span

Comment: @blackbelt I can't assume anything about the `ClickableSpan` inside. In particular, they can be subclasses that override `updateDrawState`.

Comment: you could have a state. Something like a member variable for the ClickableSpannable sublcass, that returns when the status is clicked. It is hacky tough

Comment: @blackbelt I can't modify the subclass. I could use a wrapper. But if the click reaches the Spannable then I would be missing the click handler of the view, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For automatic links you can use TextView.setLinksClickable( false );

For others change movement method  to ScrollingMovementMethod.

```
   tv.setMovementMethod( ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance() );
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `ScrollingMovementMethod`. Interesting. However, it also disables the view interaction. I guess the span still eats the click.

Comment: What iteraction it disables? I just made a small test and onClick is working. Did you use both setLinksClickable(false) and setMovementMethod?

Comment: Very interesting, I have a sample where onClick is called. I use 4.4, what version do you have? Also what kind of spans your test has?

Comment: I'm dealing with legacy code so there might be something else at play. I'll dig further and update accordingly. Apologies.

Comment: Found the problem. I had to do `setMovementMethod(null)` to propagate the click to the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

> In other words, I would like to disable all links in a given Spannable.

Then find and remove the `URLSpan` or `ClickableSpan` objects from the `Spannable`.

> But I would loose other properties (e.g., bolding), wouldn't I?

Then find and *replace* the `URLSpan` or `ClickableSpan` objects from the `Spannable` with some other spans that have the styling you want.

Comment: I can't assume anything about the spans. They can be `ClickableSpan` subclasses that override `updateDrawState`.